# HTML5/Javascript input readonly state swiching on IOS using XCode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, html

I have this input tag in my html :

```
<input id="g_name" name="g_name" type="text" readonly/>
```

With the following code attached to a touch event on another element:

```
var el = document.getElementById('g_name');
el.value = 'test string';     // set an initial value
el.readOnly = false;          // disengage readonly
el.focus();                   // set focus
```

When I compile through xcode to iphone 4s with IOS 6.0.1, the input element gets focus, and the soft keyboard pops up, but I am unable to edit the field. How do I disengage readonly? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="g_name" name="g_name" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: Tried that! same result. I also programmatically set readOnly to true prior to the event with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById('g_name');
el.value = 'test string';
el.removeAttribute("readonly");
el.focus();
```

Comment: thanks i hadn't tried that, but sadly it produces the same result.